# MODX getting RESOURCES as html

Tags: html, export, modx

We are a school having our old website with MOD X, having a lot of resources (especially our archive) which get cached as html data. My chief was asking if there is a possibility to "save" those cached archive html-sites or download them so we can import them into the "new" contao system or just link them as pure html-files???
i hope you guys can help me.
best regards

Answer (score 0):

please let me know what MODX version you use. And send cached page as example. 
Generally speaking export is possible(but depends on version).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of possible action to migrate data from MODx to other cms. Last month I had an issue like yours. And because my old client wants to use WP from now, I created a list of resources in JSON format, with all relevant fields for Wordpress import, and imported them to the Wordpress. Directories with images, I moved manually to the new location.

Just create a new MODx template in JSON format and call relevant fields, with getResources or pdo.

For me, MODx was the best CMS, and in all situation, you have a good solution.